# how to change the content width in wordpress [panoramic theme]?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, header

I am working on Ponoramic Theme by Wordpress.com.

I want to have full width for my website. There is one template available in that theme known as 'full-width template'.

But still, that is not giving full width to me.

for the reference, this is the website address..

[www.iclaa2017.com](http://iclaa2017.com).

How to change the width to be full like the header-image which is the home page right under the navigation bar?

Header also has to be in full-width. I am using logo identity to  fit my header area with the image.

Comment: please add some code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below code it should work for you, this will make ur site 100% width

```
.site-container, .fl-row-fixed-width{
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 100%!important;
}
```

Comment: Oh..great...it worked...

Comment: May I know..how to remove the padding on the left and right..since I wanted to have image for full length as in the header image just down the header..@Rajul